# How to set position of label in multiplot?

Tags: label, gnuplot

I have

```
Row1 = "set tmargin screen 0.92; set bmargin screen 0.40"   # Top and bottom margins
Row2 = "set tmargin screen 0.40; set bmargin screen 0.20"
Col1 = "set lmargin screen 0.07; set rmargin screen 0.50"   # Left and right margins
Col2 = "set lmargin screen 0.50; set rmargin screen 0.87"

set label "LABEL" at 0.4,0.2
```

What does 0.4,0.2 mean? It is not coordinates of the first graph, it is not in the same units like margins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check `help label` and `help coordinates`.

Form gnuplot help:

> The commands set arrow, set key, set label and set object allow you to
>   draw something at an arbitrary position on the graph. This position is
>   specified by the syntax:

```
{<system>} <x>, {<system>} <y> {,{<system>} <z>}
```

> Each  can either be first, second, polar, graph, screen, or
>   character.
>
> ...
>
> If the coordinate system for x is not specified, first is used. If
>   the system for y is not specified, the one used for x is adopted.

So, in your case it means the label is placed at coordinates 0.4 of x1-axis and 0.2 of y1-axis.